# Adding an element to an array of a mongoDB property using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a mongoDB collection that is full of documents that look like that:

```
{
firstName,
lastName, 
birthdate, 
phone, 
email, 
hashedPassword,
groups
}
```

groups is as an array of documents that look like that:

```
{
   gid,
   score
}
```

Whenever a user is added to a group I want to add a new document to the 'groups' (and remove one when he gets out of a group).

How do I do this with Node.js?

Using mongoDB shell its easy cause I can use update with $push but as far as I know I cant use `$push` with node.js....

Thanks!!

Comment: Are you using mongoDB with monk or something?

Comment: Just the mongoDB driver for node.js (require('mongodb'))

Comment: You can use `$push`; have you tried it?